# How to make webpack less verbose?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

**This** is *Wes Craven's New Nightmare*!

[image]

Why do I even need this horror on every little bit of change? How can I turn off these notifications?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add `--quiet` and `--no-info` to webpack-dev-server's command line: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#webpack-dev-server-cli

If you use webpack in watch mode, you can put `| awk '{if ($0 !~ /^ *\[[0-9]*\]/) {print} else {if ($0 ~ /\[built\]/) {print}}}'` after it, which will print all output except files that were not rebuilt.

Comment: What if I don't use dev server?

Comment: I need some information, e.g. I want to know that particular chunk was recompiled and built successfully, but I don't care about chunks which wasn't changed

Comment: If you use watch mode you can grep for [built] and it will show you only the things that were rebuilt. I think for other behavior you'll need to open an issue.

Comment: Those two flags do not make a difference for me.

Comment: @pete-hodgson why did you change the `grep` to `grep -v`? If you want to see only rebuilt files, that's what you want.

Comment: @pete-hodgson I changed the filter to awk because I could not make perl do the more sophisticated filtering it does now.

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov see my answer below for `express` version.

Comment: What is that `awk` command? My console thinks that *'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,* (Win 10 PowerShell)...

Answer (score 35):

You can use Webpack CLI's [`--display` option](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#stats-options) to set the verbosity of the stats output. Here are the [available values](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/).

E.g.

```
--display=minimal
```

In Webpack 5:

```
--stats=minimal
```

Comment: In Webpack 5 it's `--stats=minimal`

Comment: What is stats output? Is it related to log level?

Answer (score 11):

From webpack docs:

> The stats option lets you precisely control what bundle information gets displayed. This can be a nice middle ground if you don't want to use quiet or noInfo because you want some bundle information, but not all of it.
>
> For webpack-dev-server, this property needs to be in the devServer object.

```
//example with module.exports in webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  //...
  stats: 'minimal'
};

//example with dev-sever in webpack.config.js
dev-sever: {
  //...
  stats: 'minimal'
}
```

See docs for other options including `errors-only`, `none`, `verbose` and more.

ref: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/

Comment: this one worked for me... adding it to the devserver options. seems like it was overriding the general config I gave at first. not documented in the options from devserver. I suppose in some point must be clear that some general options are available for dev server? heck, many thx

Comment: it is indeed documented https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-stats-

Comment: I dont know why this answer isn't higher. This is the right way to do things. Particularly, look at this part: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#extending-stats-behaviours

Comment: It is not working for me so why I guess it has no points. If I put { stats: 'verbose' } it does not log any info. The console is almost empty.

Comment: This is the best answer. Works for me with Webpack 5 and DevServer 4.9.3 (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/).

Answer (score 4):

Use webpack's stats options.

For example, to remove the hundreds of lines generated by chunks:

```
stats: {
    chunks: false
}
```

To remove information about modules:

```
stats: {
    chunkModules: false
}
```

See [the stats documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/) for many more options.

Answer (score 3):

I changed Haken's grep statement slightly so that it works on initial load and when I update a JS files as well.

Here is the code snippet in my package.json.

```
scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run dev | grep -v \"\\[\\d*\\]\""
}
```

This will filter out all lines that contains patterns like [231], [232], etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [karma-webpack](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/karma-webpack), you can place this into your config file:

```
webpackMiddleware: {
 noInfo: true,
 stats: 'errors-only'
}
```

`noInfo: false` display no info to console (only warnings and errors) [documentation](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware)

`stats: 'errors-only'` only output when errors happen [documentation](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/node.js-api#stats)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `express` version then you can include `noInfo` option:

```
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo: true
}));
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I prefer a solution where I'm not having to grep output.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Webpack-Dev-Server config file, you can hook into the API.

Using `noInfo: true` will disable informational messages unless you have an error.

Using `quiet: true` removes all console information, even errors.

Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#api

Answer (score 1):

Run `webpack` with the `--hide-modules` option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and my solution is not new, but details previous answers. In your webpack.dev.js you can use the following configuration for devServer. Pay attention to the `stats` section:

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    port: 3420,
    inline: true,
    stats: {
      colors: true,
      chunks: false,
      hash: false,
      version: false,
      timings: false,
      assets: false,
      children: false,
      source: false,
      warnings: true,
      noInfo: true,
      contentBase: './dist',
      hot: true,
      modules: false,
      errors: true,
      reasons: true,
      errorDetails: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
    }),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`quiet` and `no-info` didn't do anything useful for me. 
Instead I ended up using a grep filter.

```
npm run dev | grep -v "node_modules\|\[built\]"
```

This will remove any line containing `[built]` or `node_modules`, which makes it easier to see the actual build errors without scrolling through a bunch of lines of terminal output.

I've put this in the `scripts` section of my package.json so I can use `npm run dev-quiet` to get the filtered output log.

Answer (score 0):

When using [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware), you now have to use [`logLevel`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#loglevel) instead of `noInfo` inside the config options ([as of 12/18/17](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/blob/0f9e0635863add14db27fa7ab0392ec4d4b2a8ab/breaking-changes.md)).

**Example:**

```js
require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
    logLevel: "warn", // set the logLevel
});
```